# Interceptor ignored

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a JAVA based configuration with this line:

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor((HandlerInterceptor) new LogInterceptor());
}
```

of which the preHandle does only one thing:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    request.setAttribute("test", "something for fun");
    return true;
}
```

in the JSP page, I call the attribute:

```
test: ->${pageContext.request.getAttribute("test")}<-
```

resulting in:

```
test: -><-
```

If I call the method directly from the servlet, it works properly.

What have I done wrong?

I use NetBeans Java Web Web Application with Spring MVC 4.0.1

I suspect this is a bug

Comment: I made a test case in which I use the XML configuration, and that one does find the interceptor and gives the correct outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Add path patterns where you register your interceptor. You probably have them in your XML configuration and may forgot in java config.

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor((HandlerInterceptor) new LogInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
}
```

Comment: That does not make a difference. When I use XML configuration without the path Patterns, it works fine. The issue is that the two way of configuring it do different things.